# Kafka ordering issue

Tags: apache-kafka

i have a kafka topic with 1 partition, but i have let's say 3 messages in a transaction m1, m2, m3. The order in which they are produced is m1, m2 and m3. but somehow due to network latency, it reached  in the order m3, m2 and few minutes after m1. then how do i handle it ?
As my consumer would have already consumed m3 and then m2 and then m1.
This will create issue in the application as the m1 is for create operation, while the m2 & m3 can be an update or reversal operation.
I'm using proper keys and timestamp when producing the messages, but what will be the behaviour of kafka in this? And how to handle it ?

Comment: Is your producer waiting for success response for each message before sending the next? Or are there multiple producers? Assuming 1 producer, That would take care of any network latency issue and is required if you really want sequential processing of your messages. Also your consumer should fetch messages 1 by 1 and not by batches.

Comment: We need to see your producer code. Sounds like it isn't working the way you think. For example, have you tried adding producer callback handlers to see what order data was really sent?